# Phone not mounting as a drive when "Connect USB storage" is clicked

Tags: usb-connection-mode

I have a Samsung Galaxy S, using the default firmware (version 2.2).  It is configured to select "Mass Storage" when plugged in via micro USB.

When I plug the phone into the cable, I receive the "Click here to connect via USB" button.

However, when I click it, the phone thinks for a bit and then tells me that it's connected; yet Windows makes no mention of it and the drives are not accessible from the computer.  It has worked in the past, but has apparently decided I am no longer worthy or something.

I have rebooted both the phone and the computer with no change in behaviour.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there something obvious I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I used to have this problem, where the phone connects once and then again I connect and face the same problem as you, then again I restart my phone and it is ok. This happens if you disconnect your phone with out ejecting the drive properly, one remedy is reset. But mine is ok after a few times, hope yours will be too.