# How do I mount my phone?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, usb-connection-mode, usb-debugging, mount

I'm super puzzled because my phone used to just appear when I plugged it in. It doesn't anymore and The development options are definitely set to allow USB debugging. The phone is charging via USB but doesn't appear in `lsusb`:

```
[0 amanda@luna android-sdk-linux_86]$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 17ef:4807 Lenovo UVC Camera
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 413c:1003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 08ff:2810 AuthenTec, Inc. AES2810
Bus 003 Device 013: ID 413c:2010 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 014: ID 046d:c001 Logitech, Inc. N48/M-BB48 [FirstMouse Plus]
```

`adb devices -l` shows nothing.

Based on [some instructions on the internet](http://www.computerandyou.net/2012/01/how-to-fix-android-samsung-galaxy-s2-not-recognized-on-linux/), I also went into my Wireless and Network settings and changed the USB connection settings to "Mass storage" -- they were set to "Ask on connection" though I definitely wasn't getting asked. I don't get any [Click here to connect via USB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18913/phone-not-mounting-as-a-drive-when-connect-usb-storage-is-clicked) alert either.

I wouldn't be surprised if I clicked some "stop asking me" button at some point, but I don't see how to undo that.  What else should I be doing to mount my phone?

Answer (score 1):

I asked the [same question over on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297766/how-the-heck-do-i-mount-my-android-phone) and someone suggested it was a dodgy USB cable. I'm kind of speechless, but indeed, swapping the cable solved my problems. Now when I plug my phone in to a USB port, I get a little notice that the USB is connected. Onward.